# Update a table based on another table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have two tables:

**products**

```
| id | name        | price | type_id 
------------------------------------
| 1  | Product A   | 500   | 1
| 2  | Product B   | 600   | 3
| 3  | Product C   | 800   | 15
```

**types**

```
| id  | price | 
---------------
| 1   |       |
| 3   |       |
| 15  |       |
```

Now I want to set the price in the of the **types** table to the values in **products** table whose has the corresponding type_id

So in the types table `1 => 500, 3 => 600, 15 => 800` given the fact that type_id is unique within products table.

I tried to write a query like:

```
UPDATE types SET price = (
   SELECT sub.price FROM (SELECT p.type_id AS id, p.price AS price
                          FROM products p, types t
                          WHERE p.type_id = t.id) AS sub
   WHERE sub.id = types.id
)
```

However, the query does not get to work correctly and seems to be too complicated. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a type is attributed to only one product in maximum so:

```
UPDATE types set price = products.price 
from products where products.type_id= types.id
```

Comment: Yes. I works correctly in my case. I will accept your answer now :D